# Local Notification Firing Multiple Times And At Unscheduled Hours

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I have a local notification set up that is supposed to fire at 8am everyday and, it does except, it fires 3 times at 8am and than again at 9am and at 12pm, after that it stops and repeats the same thing the next day.

I checked if the function was being called multiple times (it wasn't ), even if it was called multiple times that wouldn't explain the firing at the wrong time. And pretty much all i could think of, re implemented the code, but to no avail.

This is how i set up the notification:

```
func setUpMainLocalNotification() {

             let notificationSettings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()

                    if notificationSettings?.types == .None {

                        return

                    }


     let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
     let currentCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
     let date = NSDate()
     let calendarComponents = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .WeekOfMonth, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)



                    calendarComponents.hour = 8

                    calendarComponents.minute = 0
                    calendarComponents.second = 0

                    currentCalendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()



                    let reminder = UILocalNotification()
                    reminder.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
                    reminder.fireDate = currentCalendar.dateFromComponents(calendarComponents)
                    reminder.alertBody = "Notification"
                    reminder.category = "CATEGORY_ID"

                    reminder.repeatInterval = .Day

                    reminder.alertAction = "Reply"
                    reminder.soundName = "sound.aif" 



                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(reminder)

}
```

**Update:**

As i was reading my own question here i noticed that i was setting the time zone after setting the hour i wanted my notification to fire at, so i moved the following line to before setting the hour and it seems to work, fires only once and at 8am.

```
currentCalendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
```

Answer (score 1):

do you cancel the previous notifications anywhere before setting up the new ones ?

Try this at the begining of your method

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, though i do handle notification cancelation. I've updated my question with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is the latest code

```
UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```